# Syntax error like what is the problem sql

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, any

```
create table salesman(
salesman_id Numeric(5) primary key,
name varchar(30),
city varchar(15),
commission decimal(3,2)   
);

insert into salesman(salesman_id,name,city,commission)
values  
 (5001, "James Hoog", "New York", 0.15),
 (5002 , "Nail Knite" , "Paris" , 0.13),
 (5005 , "Pit Alex" , "London" , 0.11),
 (5006 , "Mc Lyon" , "Paris" , 0.14),
 (5007 , "Paul Adam" , "Rome" , 0.13),
 (5003 , "Lauson Hen" , "San Jose" , 0.12)
 ;

select name
from salesman
where city = any ("New York","London","Rome");
```

why is error 1064 coming when everything seems to be right
i just want to get the salesman name belonging to any one of the above mentioned cities.

Comment: Try single quotes instead of double quotes

Comment: Which RDBMS?  What is the *exact* error?  (Syntax errors often have a way of pointing out *where* the syntax becomes invalid.)  "everything seems to be right" is a bit of a non-starter when something clearly isn't right.

Answer (score 2):

Error 1064 is a syntax error for MySQL.
Your syntax is incorrect because you cannot use the ANY operator without a subquery.
Proper syntax would be to use the IN operator like so:

```
SELECT name FROM salesman WHERE city IN ('New York','London','Rome');
```

Comment: I can do the task but I want to know why is this not working specifically. Are you sure any cannot be used without subqueries cause I saw some examples elsewhere basically on other sites where they were using it without subqueries.           What my question specifically is that does any other reason other than "any" not being used with subquery exist?

Comment: Fix the quotes to be single quotes first.